# How to make progress bar with minute interval?

Tags: react-native, progress-bar, setinterval, react-native-ios

**library used react-native progress
for making an progress bar**

```
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';  

<Progress.Bar progress={0.3} width={200} />
```

Answer (score 0):

use this library  react-native progress
initial value set to 0

```
 const [progressBarValue, setProgressBarValue] = useState(0) 

 useEffect(() => {
     const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setProgressBarValue((prev) => {
        if (prev >= 1.2) {
          setCongratulations('Congratulations')
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          return 1.120;
        } else {
          return prev + 0.01;
        }
      });
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);
```

**render code**

```
  <Progress.Bar progress={progressBarValue} width={width-50} color={'rgba(221,196,145, 1)'}/>
```